# Import identical excel files into access with multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

So, I'm trying to find ways to facilitate recombining data in excel sheets using access. What I am trying to do is take multiple excel files that are all identically formatted and concatenate them into a contiguous table. Right now I have a VBA function that will allow me to target one excel worksheet across a directory of excel files and combine them into one access table. My question is, how can I go about doing that same thing, but for EVERY worksheet in the directory in one shot, instead of running and modifying the code for every worksheet.

TL;DR You have 100 excel files, each with 7 worksheets in them. The formatting is identical, but the data is different. How do I take all 100 files and combine their worksheets into 7 respective MS Access tables?

****** ISSUE HAS BEEN SOLVED. WORKING CODE AS FOLLOWS *******

Module 1 named SingleModule:

```
    Option Compare Database

    Public Function importExcelSheets(Directory As String, TableName As String, WkShtName As String) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
      Dim strDir As String
      Dim strFile As String
      Dim I As Long
      I = 0
      If Left(Directory, 1) <> "\" Then
          strDir = Directory & "\"
      Else
          strDir = Directory
      End If
          strFile = Dir(strDir & "*.XLSX")
      While strFile <> ""
          I = I + 1
          strFile = strDir & strFile
          Debug.Print "importing " & strFile
          DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , TableName, strFile, True, WkShtName
          strFile = Dir()
      Wend
      importExcelSheets = I
    End Function
```

Module 2 named MultipleModule:

```
Public Function importMultipleExcelFiles(Directory As String) As Long
For x = 1 To 7
Dim TableName As String
Dim WkShtName As String
    TableName = Choose(x, "Table1", "Table2", "Table3", "Table4")
    WkShtName = Choose(x, "Table1!", "Table2!", "Table3!", "Table4!")
    Call SingleModule.importExcelSheets(Directory, TableName, WkShtName)
Next x
End Function
```

Use the following command in the Immediate Window to execute (Make sure you change the filepath):

```
? importMultipleExcelFiles("C:\Excel File Directory")
```

SIDE NOTE:

You can target one worksheet using the following command on SingleModule in the Immediate Window:

```
? importExcelSheets("C:\FilePath", "TableName", "WkShtName!")
```

Comment: You can do this using SQL, google SQL Insert Into from Excel, something like `......FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;Database='c:\excelsheet.xlsx'].[Sheet1$]`  then you can use Currentdb.execute or docmd.runsql to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't see how your TableName was going into the procedure.  Use the FOR-NEXT with the CHOOSE function, when you're calling the importExcelSheets function.

```
for x= 1 to 7
   TableName = choose(x, "Table1", "Table2"...)
   WkShtName = choose(x, "ContactDetails!", ...)
   importExcelSheets  Dir, TableName, WkshtName
next x
```

Comment: your code then works as original, and all you need to do is define WkShtName variable and add it to your TransferSpreadsheet command.

Comment: I apologize, I'm really new to VBA and MS-Access. You may need to elaborate on the steps a little more. I really appreciate your help.

 I've been using the Immediate Window to run the code. Are you suggesting that I create a new module using this code and reference my original code?

Comment: You must be calling the ImportExcelSheets from a call function right?  Use the code I gave you in another procedure, and run that one.  It will call your your original code as is, but just edit the following:    `Public Function importExcelSheets(Directory As String, TableName As String, WkShtName as string) As Long`   and replace "ContactDetails!" with WkShtName.

Comment: eg.  `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , TableName, strFile, True, WkShtName`

Comment: With some properly applied googling, I figured it out! Thank you so much, you were a big help!

Comment: Glad it worked.  For future reference, it's not necessary to create a new module though, the procedure would have worked in the same one, eliminating the need to reference "SingleModule."   (I never use the call command either)